# Score mismatch when filtered by different time periods

Tags: support, users-page

Can anyone explain to me why my scores listed on Biology.SE for ['this year'](https://biology.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=year) and ['all'](https://biology.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) differ by 101 points? I only joined two months ago so they should be the same, shouldn't they? Is this a bug?

Comment: Your association bonus isn't counted as part of your score.

Comment: But then the bonus shouldn't appear with either filter, should it? Why does it appear with one and not the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'all' shows the total reputation. As you see it right now in your profile -  the sum of the association bonus and the reputation you earn.

All the other tabs show only the earned points, and thus exclude the association bonus.